# performance issue when iterating a generic List in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, list, generics

Suppose we have these business objects with some properties in common:

```
public class A
{
    // Properties in common
    public int Common { get; set; }
    public string aValue { get; set; }
    // Some other goes here.
}

public class B
{
    // Properties in common
    public int Common { get; set; }
    public string bValue { get; set; }

    // Some other goes here.
}
```

And in our business logic we have two lists like these ones:

```
List<A> aList = new List<A>();
List<B> bList = new List<B>();
```

(and suppose we have these lists populated with at least 100 instances for each one)
OK, lets begin with our problem, we need to iterate over the aList in order to set one property of each instance in the bList that of course match with the property in common, like this:

```
foreach (A a in aList)
{
    B b = bList.Find(x => x.Common == a.Common);
    if (b != null)
        b.bValue = a.aValue;
}
```

Does anyone knows a better way to improve this operation because it is causing our app takes too much time to be completed?

thanks,

Comment: I don't believe that 100 elements can cause any performance problem. How many are there?

Comment: @gdoron It depends on how often you call this function :)

Comment: @gdoron I think I forgot mention that the app is for Windows Mobile device, so the app is limited by the resources of the mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not perform well because `Find` on a list is linear. The resulting algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

You should make a `Dictionary` from the `bList` on the common attribute, and look up by the key instead of searching with `Find`; dictionary lookup is `O(1)` amortized, so it will make your algorithm linear in the length of the list.

```
var dict = bList.ToDictionary(b => b.Common);
foreach (A a in aList) {
    B b;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(a.Common, out b) {
        b.bValue = a.aValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer including big O :D

Comment: Couldn't it just be `B b = dict[a.Common]; if (b != null){        b.bValue = a.aValue;}`

Comment: @gdoron Unfortunately, the `[]` operator will fail if the item is not there. `TryGetValue` is a more straightforward choice than `Contains+[]`, because it lets you avoid an extra lookup by key.

Answer (score 2):

To efficiently look a value up, given a certain key you would not use a list, but a dictionary. To find a specific item in a list takes O(N), in a dictionary takes O(1).

```
Dictionary<int, B> bDict = new Dictionary<int, B>();
foreach (B b in bList) bDict.Add(b.Common, b);

foreach (A a in aList) {
  if (bDict.ContainsKey(a.Common)) 
    bDict[a.Common].bValue = a.aValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy your bList to a dictionary-type container with Common as the key and use that rather than bList itself in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you do a join in linq it will do a hash join for you on the two lists which would save you manually creating a dictionary as is suggested in the other answers. I don't have studio on this machine to whip you up a sample, will try to update later.

Linq may even be smart enough to not fire up a hash join if the number of items is very small.

Edit:
Give something like this a spin:

```
var joined = from a in aList
                    join b in bList on a.Common equals b.Common
                    select new {
                            A = a,
                            B = b
                    };

            foreach (var item in joined)
            {
                    item.B.bValue = item.A.aValue;
            }
```

Comment: +1 this is the answer I would have given. Using join also saves you from having to use TryGetValue or some other means of handling mismatched items in the source list.